# Linux: using Evernote from Emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs, evernote

I would like to know if there is any software enabling us to use Evernote from Emacs in Linux. I edit my notes with Emacs in a text file that has grown to several MBs over the last 10 years, and I would like to be able to have it syncing with Evernote, and be able to do things like add images to it as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/emacs-evernote-mode/ is working.   I have used it successfully.

Comment: `404. That's an error.`

Answer (score 1):

Evernote uses HTML behind the scenes, perhaps you could be something similar using dropbox or something similar to provide the syncing?

I realize that was not the answer you were looking for, but short of using the Evernote API and making it work with emacs I do not believe it is possible to edit evernote notes with other editors.